# Samsung Galaxy S2 bricked?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, rom, kernel, miui

I own a galaxy sII. 3 weeks back, I downloaded and flashed the MIUI ICS rom on my phone. A week later I tried to update the ROM through ROM Manager. Everything went fine except when after flashing the latest ROM, the phone restarted and displayed the error:

```
[ RST_STAT = Ax20000000 ]
KERNEL PANIC UPLOAD MODE
```

I entered into Download Mode - ODIN and tried to connect my PC to the phone but the PC failed to recognize my device, throwing the error - 'Device Malfunctioned'. It's been 2 weeks and I'm perplexed as to what to do next.

I can enter ODIN Mode but cannot get my PC to connect to the phone. I installed the drivers manually, but ODIN doesn't recognize my phone. I connected to different PCs with different USB cables, still no luck.

If it does connect, it disconnects immediately. Also, PC fails to recognize the device, but the phone charges through the USB cable.

*Any* help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

My PC is running on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Try installing Kies from [here](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/GT-I9100LKAXEU-downloads), then reboot your phone and PC and try Odin again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the USB pin of the phone had become faulty and needed to be replaced.